# About the usage of "about the same" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, expressions

> Jim, Jack, Raul, Kim, Beti are the members of this group. Jim spent
>   100 euros, but Jack spent 10 euros. **About the same difference** is
>   between Jim and each of the other members.

The last sentence is meant to say that Raul and Kim and Beti each spent around 10 euros. So, is "about the same difference" used correctly in that sentence? Or I should say some other way?

Comment: The past form of *spend* is *spen**t***.

Comment: Why don’t you just say that the others spent 10 euros?  Is Jim upset that he’s spending so much more than the others?  Or is this a math problem?